# What does an array index minus a character mean in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


int calculate(char *target, char *data)
{
    int count = 0;

    char letters[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        letters[i] = '\0';  //same as java ''
        printf("%d : %c\n", i, letters[i] );
        /* code */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < target[i]; ++i)
    {

        letters[target[i] - 'A'] = target[i];
        printf("%d : %c\n",i,target[i] );

        /* code */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data[i]; ++i)
    {
        if(letters[data[i] - 'A'])
        {
            count++;
        }
        /* code */
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int result;
    /* code */
    char target[20];
    char data[20];
    printf("Enter the data\n");
    scanf("%s", data);
    printf("Enter the target\n");
    scanf("%s", target);

    result = calculate(target,data);

    printf("%d\n",result );

    return 0;
}
```

The main purpose of this sample program is to check for similar words in data and add their occurrences.
for example

```
Target --> DOG
data --> GOAT
```

> result would be equal to 2 because O & G appears once in data and adding them up gives 2

My problem is, when it got to the second and the third for loop, I barely understand whats going on inside the loop where `target[i] - 'A'`except that targets index is being assigned to letters

What does it mean for an array index to minus a character or what is the purpose here?

Comment: `target[i]` is some character (for example, `'C'`).  `'C' - 'A'` is 2 (if you're using ASCII) because `'C'` is two letters after `'A'` in the alphabet.

Comment: In C, `'x'` is just an integer, with the *value* of the character `x` in the default character set of your C compiler. So if `target[i]` is `'y'`, `target[i] - 'x'` will point to item "value of ('y') - value of ('x')". Since `x = 'A'` the subtraction will be the *n* th character of "A...Z" (base 0; and target[i] must be an alphabetic uppercase).

Comment: To solve the "check for similar words in data and add their occurrences", there really is no need to do "array index minus a character".  Instead count the occurrence of each into an `array[UCAHR_MAX+1]` (e.g. 256) and _then_ concern yourself with letters only.  OTOH, for short strings, this  OP's approach is OK.

Comment: In order to understand such expressions/calculations, try to use temporary variables e.g., int char_array_index = target[i] - 'A'; (same goes for data[i] - 'A').  In programming languages the character is internally represented by it's ASCII value.  So using the binary '-' or '+' means you are finding the relative offset between 'A' and other character.  In your case such an offset becomes an index into the array where you are storing the corresponding letter in letters[].

Comment: As a good programming practice, add meaningful comments to your code so that it becomes apparent to readers as well as to you when you read it later :-)

Comment: In the second loop where i < targets[i], it's comparing 0 < 'D' how does that work?

Comment: Take a look at [**ASCII Table.com**](http://www.asciitable.com/), it will help explain the value/character relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do with letters[] is vague.

Having mentioned that and considering the fact that target[i] & 'A' are characters subtracting them is like subtracting their ASCII code correspondents. In essence, with

```
target[i] - 'A'
```

you get the difference between the two characters and it is evident that you are trying to use this difference as in index to `letters` array. For example if target[i] is 'C', doing `'C'-'A'` gives you 2 and since arrays indexing starts from zero, the index 2 actually points to the 3rd character in the array.

Also, for the above reason there is a high chance that your program will malfunction because if you enter something like "Tiago Rodriguez" for the `target` string, you will encounter a stack overflow  because ASCII code for `i` is 105 and doing `target[i] - 'A'` will give you 40 - ie 105 - 65 - as the result but you have assigned only 26 bytes(assuming that char is 1 byte) for `letters`.

Also, it is dangerous using `scanf` to input strings for three reasons -

1. It stores the value only up to the space.
2. The rest of the input buffer is used for next scanf statement.
3. It has no mechanism to check for buffer overruns.

For example if you enter "Tiago Rodriguez" for `data`, "Tiago" will be stored in `data` and "Rodriguez" will be stored in `target`

You could replace scanf with `fgets`. For example :

```
printf("Enter data ");
fgets(data,20,stdin);
```

`fgets` above allows you to store upto 19 characters - including the spaces and newline - and `stdin` is the file descriptor for standard input. For more information on fgets check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Answer (score 4):

Subtracting `A` will map `A` to `0`, `B` to `1`, etc with the ASCII character set.

Since array indexing is zero based in C, this effectively allows use of uppercase letters to determine the index an array element.

There is a limitation as this approach assumes the letters `A` through `Z` are contiguous in the character set.    That assumption is true for ASCII, but there are also real, standardized, character sets where this is not true, and real-world C compilers which use those character sets.

Comment: @dreamlax "C standard guarantees that A through to F are contiguous" --> is not support by the C spec.

Comment: I just woke up ... I don't know what I was thinking!

Answer (score 3):

An array index is the thing you put in the subscript operator (the `[]`), so `i` is the array index. And `target[i]` is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object - it evaluates to *the element*, not the index.

All that being said, `target` is an array of characters, so `target[i]` is a character and, as you know, `'A'` is a character too. Subtracting two characters has analogous semantics to subtracting two integers: it gives you their difference in the character set space. In this case, it tells you how far a particular character is from the character `'A'`. Assuming a character set where letters are consecutive, `'A' - 'A'` will be `0`, `'B' - 'A'` will be `1`, `'C' - 'A'` will be `2`, and so on. Basically, that subtraction maps the character `'A'` to the number `0`, the character `'B'` to the number `1`, the character `'C'` to the number `2`, and so on.

The `letters` array presumably has a slot for each letter of the English alphabet, where some information about the character `'A'` is stored at index `0`, information about the character `'B'` is stored at index `1`, and so on. The mapping described previously helps find the index for each letter of the alphabet so that the program can read or write information about that character at the corresponding slot of that array.

Comment: `'B' - 'A'` is 1 *assuming a character set where they are consecutive*, not necessarily always true.